# Pass a variable in a styled-components in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I try to pass a variable in a component that uses styled-components

This is how I call the component

```
<td><p><LimitBar width = {perc}/> {perc}%</p></td>
```

`perc` is a number between 0 and 100

Then, the LimitBar is like this

```
const LimitBarBorder = styled.span`
      ...some css
`;

const LimitBarColored = styled.span`
        ...some more css
        width: ${props => props.width};
    `;

const LimitBar = (width) => (
      <LimitBarBorder>
        <LimitBarColored width={width}></LimitBarColored>
      </LimitBarBorder>
    );

export default LimitBar;
```

But, then, the HTML code is like this

```
<td>
    <p>
        <span class="sc-pHKzq izKVhe">
            <span width="[object Object]" class="sc-pQFoF bkUWrD"></span>
        </span> 85%
    </p>
</td>
```

As you can see, the width parameter passed as object, while it is just a number. I am new on React and try to do it with online tutorials and official documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const LimitBar = ({width}) => (
  <LimitBarBorder>
    <LimitBarColored width={width}></LimitBarColored>
  </LimitBarBorder>
);

export default LimitBar;
```

It doesn't look like you're passing in the prop correctly.

Comment: Now, I get `<span width="85" class="sc-pQFoF dsLEU"></span>` without applying the CSS rule.

Comment: What css rule if I may ask? Because your question was how to pass in the variable.

Comment: It is in the question. Sorry if wasn't clear `width: ${props => props.width};`

Comment: how are you able to tell that the width of 85 on the span element is not being applied?

Comment: because it's not in the developer console, in the rest with the css rules.

Comment: It looks like you're asking two different questions at the same time. But that was not in your question which you posted. You said you were getting an object instead of a number. If you're not seeing it there it is probably because there is not unit attached to the width.  So you can attach it to your variable to see if will show up. Other than that I'll suggest you create a different question for that.

Comment: Actually, that is the problem. Changing it to `width: ${props => props.width + '%'};`, together with the changed in your answer, fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
width: ${props => props.width};
```

You are setting the width to be equal to the **function** that takes `props` as parameter and returns `props.width`. To fix, just insert `props.width` instead:

```
width: ${props.width};
```

**Edit:** Also see Jonathan's answer and adjust your function component accordingly.

Comment: With or without the Jonathan's change, changing the width as you suggest raises this error on console `props is not defined`

Comment: @Tasos What about `this.props.width` ?